# Add value to arraylist from edittext inside recyclerview

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a recylerview which contains several edit text and 2 textview beside each edit text. Initially I want empty edit text when activity is loaded, after that putting some values in 1 or more edit text randomly. I do not want to loose the value on scroll up or down. Please provide a solution for that if possible.

Comment: We're not really here to do your homework. If you have a specific question, you can ask that.

Comment: I found the solution